# Theme changing doesn't influence disabled control theme on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I suppose, this is a bug.

To reproduce, start the application with dark theme on Windows Phone.
After the application has been launched, change the theme to light.
And after that click "Enable" button.
You will see "Sample" button disappear. because it's theme is still dark.

```
<Page x:Class="ButtonThemeTest.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonTest"
                Content="Sample"
                IsEnabled="False" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
                Content="Enable" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2"
                Click="ButtonBase_OnClick2"
                Content="Disable" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonTest.IsEnabled = true;
}

private void ButtonBase_OnClick2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonTest.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the button's control template to see if it's designed improperly?

Comment: button's control template is default

Comment: I've tried to change button's RequestedTemplate to Light. But it couldn't help.

Comment: Even the `Button` has a ControlTemplate. Does it have a Visual State defined for Enabled that is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have found is to get Button style from generic.xaml and add a storyboard to Normal visual state like this :

```
<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="{ThemeResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

using Visual studio Blend set style to the button.

Comment: I agree, this looks like decision, but in this case setting template to the button is not desirable by design.